List all views and their elements from controller in ASP.NET Core MVC using C#
Is it possible to list all views within a project and their elements like below in ASP.NET Core MVC using C#?
Actually I want to do that with reflection in C#. Please give me a solution.




Area
Controller
View
Element
asp-for
Id
Name




CMMS
Equipments
Index
button

create
create


CMMS
Equipments
Create
input
Name
Name



CMMS
Equipments
Create
select
LocationId




Production
Products
List
table


tblProductsList


Production
Products
Edit
select

ProductTypeId





Just use swagger to discover everything. It splits by controllers by default. Also for areas you should be able to use this SO post

An easy solution is to use htmlAgility pack to parse all the elements. I don't know how to achieve this using "reflection".
    public class Info
    {
        public string Area { get; set; }
        public string Controller { get; set; }
        public string View { get; set; }
        public string Element { get; set; }
        public string aspfor { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

Non-area HomeController (Just note that this code only search cshtml in "areas" folder)
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var infos = new List<Info>();

            var viewFiles = Directory.GetFiles("Areas" ,"*.cshtml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (var filePath in viewFiles)
            {
                var pathParas = filePath.Split("\\");

                var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
                htmlDoc.Load(filePath);

                // Get all HTML elements (nodes)
                var htmlNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                                                    .Where(node => node.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element);

                // List all HTML elements
                foreach (var node in htmlNodes)
                {
                    var info = new Info();
                    info.Element = node.Name;
                    info.Controller = pathParas[pathParas.Length - 2];
                    info.Area = pathParas[pathParas.Length - 4];
                    info.View = pathParas[pathParas.Length - 1].Split(".")[0];

                    foreach (var attribute in node.Attributes)
                    {
                        switch (attribute.Name)
                        {
                            case "asp-for":info.aspfor = attribute.Value;break;
                            case "id": info.Id = attribute.Value; break;
                            case "name": info.Name = attribute.Value; break;
                        };
                    }
                    infos.Add(info);
                }
            }
            return View(infos);
        }

Index.cshtml
@model List<Info>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Area</th>
            <th>Controller</th>
            <th>View</th>
            <th>Element</th>
            <th>asp-for</th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var info in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@info.Area</td>
                <td>@info.Controller</td>
                <td>@info.View</td>
                <td>@info.Element</td>
                <td>@info.aspfor</td>
                <td>@info.Id</td>
                <td>@info.Name</td>
 
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

Test result


